# PyCharm - remove shortcut for open help window on Mac

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am new to PyCharm. I want to disable the shortcut which open the help window on my macBook. If I press <kbd>Cmd + Shift + 7</kbd> the help area should not open.

So I went into `Settings -> Keymap` and searched for the command but nothing was found! Can someone help me?

[image: example]

Comment: It's not PyCharm specific issue. [See this answer for the solution](https://superuser.com/a/579256/4777).

Comment: OK thanks, just need to disable in keyboard settings :)